# What is the correct syntax in php in passing variable(s) in a HTML link to another form

Tags: php, html

This is what I am trying to do. I am trying pass variable(s) from one form to another. I can do it in "HTML" I would like to have done in a PHP echo statement
When I call the second program from the first program I have nothing coming back in the "GET" array. I think ($v_resource_id, $v_category_id) are not being translated correctly What I am doing wrong in my syntax ? What you see here is part of the first program or calling program

```
echo'<a href="called_form.php?var=$v_resource_id&var2=$v_category_id "target="_blank"></a>';
```

Comment: This echo is from sending part or receiving part.?

Comment: Please add more code from sending and receiving parts separately.

Comment: Sending or calling program:  $v_resource_id = 1;, v_category_id = 10; This get passed to the receiving program or called program

Comment: Called or receiving  program $v_resource_id = $_GET["v_resource_id"];      $v_category_id = $_GET["v_category_id"];  echo 'resource_id  '.$v_resource_id; echo 'category_id '.v_category_id;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the noted html error (missing quote), you are not retrieving the correct keys, you have `var` and `var2` but are trying to retrieve `v_resource_id`. You need to retrieve `$_GET['var']` and `$_GET['var2']`.

Do `print_r($_GET);` to see what is being sent via `$_GET`. You should get:

```
Array (
    [var] => whatever
    [var2] => something else
)
```

Also, you may want to use the native [query building function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) by doing `http_build_query(array('var'=>'something','var2'=>'what ever'))` to get a query string. Makes this easier and I think it takes care of `urlencode()`, you'd have to double check that.

Comment: Works!  in calling program: echo "<a href=\"called_form.php?var=$v_resource_id&var2=$v_category_id\" target=\"_blank\">here</a>";  In called program: $v_resource_id = $_GET["var"];  & $v_category_id = $_GET["var2"];

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's about proper quoting

```
echo "<a href=\"called_form.php?var=$v_resource_id&var2=$v_category_id\" target=\"_blank\">here</a>";
```

you'll use your values as `$_GET['var']` and `$_GET['var2']`

Comment: Lambda7 did not wok

Comment: I tried it a second time no $v_resource_id = $_GET["v_resource_id"]; I getting undefined variable in my called program

Comment: @jperson19468 Sorry, I was using my test script try this